# How to set local storage value to selected value in drop down Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, angular-material

I'm having a Angular JS material drop down menu and items are loading from my controller. When user clicks an item , I'm storing it value to local storage. It works well. After selecting the value , I want to set that (local storage value) value as dropdown default value.

```
  <div flex>
    <md-select ng-model="$callcenterController.selectedLanguage" ng-selected="$callcenterController.getLocalStorageItem" ng-change="$callcenterHomeController.languageChange($callcenterController.selectedLanguage.name)"  placeholder="{{$callcenterController.selectLanguageLabel}}" >
        <md-option ng-value="languages" ng-repeat="languages in $callcenterHomeController.languageList"></md-select-label>  {{ languages.name }}</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

From my controller

```
ctrl.getLocalStorageItem = localStorage.getItem('selectLanguage')

ctrl.languageChange = function (key) {
if (typeof this.selectedLanguage != 'undefined'){

  localStorage.setItem('selectLanguage', key);

  $route.reload();

}  }
```

Comment: Use the Model value to be assigned with local storage value on load as like **ctrl.defaultLanguage = localStorage.getItem('selectLanguage');** and use it in template **ng-model="$callcenterController.defaultLanguage "**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the value to the variable you bind in ng-model. In your case

```
$callcenterController.selectedLanguage
```

So:

```
Controller:

ctrl.selectedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('selectLanguage');

ctrl.languageChange = function () {
  if(ctrl.selectedLanguage) {
    localStorage.setItem('selectLanguage', ctrl.selectedLanguage);
  }
}
```

View:

```
<md-select ng-model="$callcenterController.selectedLanguage"  ng-change="$callcenterHomeController.languageChange()" >
...etc
  </md-select>
```

Comment: When it close the browser and check , it doesn't set the value. Also route.reload is not working and on change function is not working

Comment: @yBrodsky- After the refresh drop down selected value set to blank. But it stores in local storage. Please help

Comment: Is your controller reloading?